# how to return a Promise.all().then to a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return a `Promise.all()` to a function. I tried different ways but it is showing errors

### here is my code

```
// All this iam doing in my server side controller
Promise = require('bluebird');

function countByTitle(accrdnArray) {
  console.log(accrdnArray) // array of objects is printing here
  var arrayCount = countfunc(accrdnArray);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayCount)) // here it is not printing showing error 
}

function countfunc(accrdnArray) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < accrdnArray.lenght; i++) {
    var heading = accrdnArray[i].name;
    array.push(mongoCount(heading));
  }

  return Promise.all(array).then(resultantCount => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(resultantCount)); // resultanCout printing here
      return resultantCount
    })
    // Here i want to return the resultantCount to above function.        
}

function mongoCount(heading) {
  var mongoQuery = {
    "ProCategory.title": heading
  }
  return Collection.count(mongoQuery).then(function(count) {
    return {
      name: categoryTitle,
      count: count
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: `Promise.all()` accept argument as array of promise but you are trying to pass array of function . convert your function call into promise and then try.

Comment: You should show the actual errors as well.

Comment: Doesn't collection.count(...) just return a count, not a promise?

Comment: You can't return the future value of a promise. That's what promises are all about. You return a promise, then wait on it with `then`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return Promise.all(array).then(resultantCount =>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resultantCount )); // resultanCout printing here
    return resultantCount;
});
```

This part of the code returns a Promise object. So you have to use `.then()` again in your `countByTitle` function.

```
function countByTitle(accrdnArray) {
  console.log(accrdnArray) // array of objects is printing here
  var arrayCount = countfunc(accrdnArray);
  arrayCount.then(function(count) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(count));
  });
}
```